# Workbox for ASP .net application

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am looking to enable PWA for an ASP .net application and I couldn't find references that confirms if workbox can be used for this purpose.
I have in the past used workbox with web applications built using JQuery and Angular.  So I am familiar with how PWA works etc.  But I would like to know if Workbox behaves the same way for a .net application as well.
Any references would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks